# PHP timer for a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I have a `setInterval` timer and it stores its information into database. Somehow people manage to cheat me. What I need is a PHP function to calculate time since Javascript timer has started and save time in DB? Is that even possible?

Comment: So don't rely on client-provided information and calculate the times on the server using database / server provided values only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you call your PHP script using an Ajax call from setInterval.
So you can use in you're ajax complete callback :

```
var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start; // start is defined before ajax call
console.log('Execution time: ' + time);
```

If you need to calculate it form server-side, use [time()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.time.php) in PHP